# Payone Credit Card and Onepagecheckout

Tags: magento, checkout, credit-card

I'm using the IWD Onestepcheckout extension in combination with PAYONE (3.1.3). And I can't get PAYONEs payment method "Credit Card" to work.

The  $configId in payone/core/helper/config.php is empty for this payment method. I think that this causes the error.

When I use Debit Payment or Online Bank Transfer everything works fine and the $configId isn't empty.

Has anyone also had problems with Payones Credit Card and a Onestepcheckout? Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers, Chris.

---- Edit:

Now I've done the checking of data to enable and execute the order to the end.
But when paying by credit card, the check is always performed twice. The first time the system always throws the error "Parameter {} cardexpiredate faulty or missing", even though the expiration date is ok.
I suspect that something is wrong with the Javascript.

Comment: Note for others! If anyone asks to implement payone.de gateway into ruby on rails, be prepared for a hard job.. the dumbest gateway ever. Bad support, bad documentation, bad api.. in 2015 we found a client who wants payone.de in his app.. they must be relatives.

Answer (score 0):

> The $configId in payone/core/helper/config.php is empty for this payment method

Payone depends on certain methods and dom elements to be existing. For example it will make a ajax validation on payment.save() call and append it’s own values to payment form and replacing the entered data for PCI compliance sake. 
So your task here is to check wether this method payment.save is called and if the ajax validation is made and if the data that is resulted from this validation is passed to where it needs to be passed.

In order to do it you need to change:

- `layout/payone/core.xml`
- `iwd/opc/extend.js`

Detailed answer you can find [here](http://razbakov.com/magento/2015/07/15/iwd-one-page-checkout-and-payone-credit-card.html).